# Is it possible to do Git merge from another branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

Due to my laziness to use `git checkout xxx` I want to know is it possible to merge `upstream/master` into `master` from another branch. My case is like this.

```
I have `origin` which is my repo.
I have `upstream` which is repo of company.
I have `master` branch.
I have feature/fix branches that are based on `master` branch.
```

So, basically when I'm in a feature branch I run `git fetch upstream` to see is there any update on `master` branch, before I push the branch to my `origin` (for sending pull request).

If yes then

```
> git checkout master
> git merge upstream/master
> git push origin master
> git checkout my_feature_branch
> git rebase master
```

So, I'm looking for an easy way something that takes less time, possibly without switch to `master` branch. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Script it maybe?

```
#!/bin/bash
# git-merge-upstream-to-master-and-rebase
original_branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
git checkout master &&
git merge upstream/master &&        
git checkout "$original_branch" &&
git rebase master
```

You can save it somewhere in your bin path and make it executable. After that, you can start using your single awesome command:

```
$ git merge-upstream-to-master-and-rebase
```

Comment: wow, such an innovative way. Yours is a kind of out of the box thinking :) But I have not good feelings regard that since I'm looking for max two commands, first to merge `upstream/master` to my master. Second `rebase` my current branch.

Comment: Routines™—shortening people's code since the days of  Assembly. :D Anyway, I improved it a little. Check it out.